# Is it okay to return null from overriden abstract method

Tags: java, design-patterns, overriding, abstract

I have a class `SpecialSender` witch extends `abstract class Sender`. In abstract class there is method `sendFile` but my sender just sends plain String so I don't want to use `sendFile`. Is it a good practice to do:

```
    @Override
    protected String sendFile(Product product, Type type) {
        return null;
    }
```

or should use some exception or there is different way to do it in better manner e.g I shouldn't extend `Sender` at all?

Comment: How is the method documented, what does it say it can return? My point is that there is no rule here but if the documentation of the superclass says something specific you should follow that otherwise you should properly document that it returns null

Comment: do you return null because you need to return null, or because the class isn't supposed to support this action?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson `protected abstract String sendFile(Product product, Type type) throws Exception;`
just this.


@Stultuske, I return null because my class is not supposed to support this operation

Comment: @Michu93 there is a specific exception type for that: UnsupportedOperationException

Answer (score 1):

I think its better you apply [Interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

Which means instead of `Sender` class having abstract method `sendFile`.
You can have an interface like `ISendFile` with abstract/default method `sendFile`. So that required sub class of Sender can implement `ISendFile`.

Example:

```
abstract class Sender{

  protected void send();

}

interface ISendFile{

default String sendFile(Product product, Type type) {
        .......
        return string;
    }
}

class SpecialSender extends Sender{

@Override
    protected String send() {
        return null;
    }
}

class EmployeeSender extends Sender implements ISendFile {

@Override
    protected String send() {
        ......
    }

 @Override
    String sendFile(Product product, Type type) {
        .....
    }
}
```

Comment: how would this be better? You are still providing an implementation, where an implementation isn't warranted. having default methods in (new) interfaces is not really the best design IMO

Comment: In the example above the class  SpecialSender  does not have method sendFile.

Comment: agreed, but now you are changing the original starting point, without knowing whether that is an option for the OP